# Android - Show Activity by Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

I have an Activity that push Notification. If the Activity is running background i want that the notification open the activity in foreground (the same activity, not an another instance). Basically the Activity should open itself in foregroung.

this is my code (in the class MyActivity):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(2)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifica)
                .setLargeIcon(bmp)
                .setContentTitle(Titolo)
                .setContentText(Testo);



Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(),
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

mBuilder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

I also added this line in the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

But doesn't work, it create a new instance of MyActivity.
How can i do? tnx

Comment: you cant actually run activity in background when activity is not in foreground it calls the life cycle method `onStop()` .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set PendingIntent to builder before initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

I compared your code with my working code and the only difference which I see is that your context is not the same as mine.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(),
            0,
            resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Could you try to replace `getBaseContext()` with the Context from `FirebaseMessagingService`? The `FirebaseMessagingService` extends `Service`, which has a `Context`.